# how can I find an available COM port in FreeBASIC?

Tags: freebasic

I'm working on a graphical COM port monitor in FreeBASIC, but I feel kinda wrong re-compiling every time I change the computer or the adapter. Is there any way to scan for an available COM port in FreeBASIC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of the ports available using the Win32 API function [EnumPorts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or you can check the registry branch `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM`.

The following two code snippets illustrate the two ways mentioned above:

- [FreeBASIC example for EnumPorts](http://www.freebasic-portal.de/code-beispiele/system/vorhandene-ports-schnittstellen-unter-windows-ermitteln-247.html)
- [FreeBASIC example for port listing via Registry](http://www.freebasic-portal.de/code-beispiele/system/serielle-schnittstellen-com-ports-unter-windows-ermitteln-248.html)

Unfortunately, the code snippet pages are in German but the given source codes, of course, will work on non German systems, too. ;-)